# Gutenburg: Remove border of selected block

Tags: block-editor

I am writing a plugin that creates a custom block. When the block is selected/focused in the editor, a border is created abound it (blue in the current version of WP).

I would like to disable the border for the specific block type, either in JavaScript or CSS. The problem is that the block content in the editor is wider than the block border, so it looks awkward.  What would be a good solution?

EDIT (further explanation):
The content of the block is generated by the following command in the `edit` function passed to the call to  `wp.blocks.registerBlockType(...)`:

```
React.createElement('div',
        {
            className: 'IA_Presenter_Container',
            'data-block-id': props.attributes.block_id,
            'behaviour': 'adaptive'
        },
    );
```

Basically, an empty `<div>` element is created. The `<div>` element is then taken over by a complex JavaScript application which build a full GUI environment in SVG. The environment is used to build and set the preferences for a dynamic gallery which will be displayed in the active page. All this happens without leaving the editor page, and it is important to be so.

When the block is focused, it is expanded by applying the following CSS to the div (the class `IA_Designer_Full_Width` is added in script):

```
.IA_Designer_Full_Width{
    position: relative;
    width: 96vw;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -48vw !important;
    margin-right: -48vw !important;
    max-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

The result (in a prototype) can be seen below. You see the blue border overlaying the interface:
[image: The expended environment showing the blue border inside]

Comment: what's the reason that the block content is wider than the border? Wouldn't it make more sense to ask how to solve your problem, rather than how to implement a specific solution to your problem? There's a huge chance that a simple change will solve this for you, can you share your edit component?

Comment: This is a design choice (and option for the block set by the user) to allow the element to expand the full width of the window.  My problem is not that the element is bigger, but that the border is getting on the way. It is impossible to share the component because it is generated and controlled by script.

Comment: so there is no way to reproduce your problem? You need to include at least some code that people can work with to answer this question. Note that lots of existing blocks take up the full width and don't require this, it's something every block theme in existence has to handle

Comment: I added more explanation. I hope it helps. Note that here I am talking about the block as it exists in the editor, not as it is when it is rendered on the page. I am working entirely within the  `wp.blocks.registerBlockType` call. I am not using any templates at this stage.

Comment: I see, so the dimensions of the block do not match the dimensions of the contents which overflow on either side? In that case does it not make sense to fix that rather than patching over the problem by hiding the border? Even if you hid the border you would still need to solve that problem

Comment: I applied the same style to the parent, which is the `wp-block` div. It did not work with a class, as it gets changed by script, but it worked by adding a custom attribute which can be selected in CSS.  Now I need to deal with the options box which hovers on top, but it is a separate problem.

Comment: So, the solution broke with the new theme of WP6, which means that it is sensitive the theme. While it is great to make sure that the dimension of the block fits the dimension of the content, this means changing the layout of elements out of the plugin structure. Now, I feel that my original idea of changing the border styling, while leaving the layout alone, may be a less susceptible to theme differences. Any thoughts?

Comment: WP itself already solves that problem with blocks that have align-wide and align full, and has styles that attach to `data-align="full"` that bypasses the max width rules. Generally it's not a good idea to start adding CSS rules with long selectors to try and hack around it when core itself had to tackle the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the border is set by the following style definition on the block container (it is in block-editor/style.css):

```
.block-editor-block-list__layout .block-editor-block-list__block:not([contenteditable]):focus::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--wp-admin-border-width-focus) var(--wp-admin-theme-color);
  border-radius: 1px;
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Changing setting box-shadow to "none" removes the border.

Thus, adding this css will remove the border:

```
some-selector-to-the-container:focus::after{
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```